# SQL group_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I'm using world db (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html).
I would to get following columns:
city name - population - country name - list of all languages used in country - number of languages used in country - continent.

This is my query:

```
SELECT city.NAME                                       AS city_name,
       city.Population,
       country.NAME,
       Group_concat(DISTINCT countrylanguage.language) AS language,
       Count(DISTINCT countrylanguage.language)        AS lang_nr,
       country.Continent
FROM   city
       INNER JOIN country
               ON city.CountryCode = country.Code
       INNER JOIN countrylanguage
               ON Country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode
GROUP  BY city.NAME
ORDER  BY lang_nr DESC;
```

But as result I get different number of languages for same country. Why?

Comment: Include country.NAME in the GROUP BY?

Comment: @jarlh, I've tried it, but then query returns 239 rows - which is number of countries (there is about 4000 cities) because (as I believe so) query returns every country only once. In fact in this situation languages are fine, but not all cities are listed.

Comment: With both country.NAME and city.name?

Comment: can you add sample data and desired output

Comment: You would want an outer join (in this case `LEFT JOIN`) in order to get all the cities. The above query will return only those cities that have a matching country and also a matching country language.

Comment: be careful with non-standard [mysql handling of group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html), if you don't use all the columns in the group by clause which refer to nonaggregated columns in the select list, you probably do something wrong.

Comment: Nothing works. I've tried also synchronized subqueries:
SELECT c.NAME                                       AS city_name,
       c.Population,
       country.NAME,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT language) FROM countrylanguage GROUP BY countrycode WHERE countrylanguage.countrycode = c.countrycode),
       country.Continent
FROM   city As c
       INNER JOIN country
               ON c.CountryCode = country.Code
       INNER JOIN countrylanguage

But I receive an error..

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I've solved it using subqueries

```
SELECT city.name, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(countrylanguage.language) FROM countrylanguage WHERE countrylanguage.countrycode = city.countrycode GROUP BY countrylanguage.countrycode) AS languages, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM countrylanguage WHERE countrylanguage.countrycode = city.countrycode GROUP BY countrylanguage.countrycode) AS lang_nr,
city.population,
country.name
FROM city 
INNER JOIN country ON city.countrycode = country.code
ORDER BY lang_nr DESC
```